# Sssssssslither - What am I?

Tags: riddle

> Sssssssslither
>   You can read me like a book
>   I'm so tiny and compact
>   6 long years I took
>
> I can remember a lot
>   A very basic procedure
>   White is very important to me
>   Beautiful for sure

*Again, you have to pick this apart line by line!*

Comment: Snakes on a plane?

Comment: @Jiminion What, no? How'd you get that lol

Comment: That slither is messing with my head

Comment: don't tell me it's an ipad where your finger ssssslither

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are [**Python**](https://www.python.org/).

> Sssssssslither

A python is a snake.

> You can read me like a book

Python, like BASIC or COBOL, generally uses words instead of symbols to express its operators. For example, it uses `and` and `or` where C or Java would use `&&` or `||`.

> I'm so tiny and compact

Because the language is interpreted, it doesn't need all those heavyweight compilers to build a giant executable and a very small source file is all that's needed to be a complete program.

> 6 long years I took

Python 1.0 was released in 1994, and Python 2.0 in 2000.

> I can remember a lot

Python has automatic memory management and garbage collection like Java does, and therefore while it doesn't have a large memory capacity, it can remember things often.

> A very basic procedure

Not 100% sure about this one, but Python doesn't require any "main" method like C or Java does. All the code in a file is run in order without the need for any explicit containing procedure.

> White is very important to me

In Python, whitespace determines syntax levels, and so good tabbing conventions are enforced.

> Beautiful for sure

Python is a beautiful language (and pythons are generally beautiful snakes).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is right, but I like the answer.

Comment: The slithering and "important white" are what gave it away to me.

Comment: The answer is correct, but I cannot accept unless you can answer all the lines.

Comment: Which lines do I have incorrect?

Comment: I can remember a lot

Comment: @JoeZ. the heap, perhaps?

Comment: Some of these feel off. Python, compact? Can remember a lot? Very basic? These are things I associate more with other programming languages.

Comment: ^ Same. But warspyking says the answer is correct, so there's probably something we're missing here?

Comment: You're really over thinking it...

Comment: Sorry, I give up. What's the connection between Python and remembering a lot?

Comment: @warspyking isn't i can remember a lot simply referring to it being able to store allot of variables until it quits? look at the [keeping secrets chapter](http://davidbau.com/python/learning.html)

Comment: My guess for remembering a lot would be its arbitrarily large integers

Comment: The connection is it's automatic memory management

Comment: I don't see how that relates to having a large memory, but alright...

Comment: I've edited it. Is it correct now?

Comment: @warspyking: automatic memory management does not relate to size of memory at all. All it means is that the developer does not need to write code to explicitly manage memory. Perhaps a better clue would have been something like "my memory is infallible" or "I never misremember things".

Comment: @Ian MacDonald It wasn't about the size, it was about the "I can remember" part. Joe Z. Yes, accepted, could you make it look more, correct now? You doubt yourself in the answer multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

Are you a

> Disk?

Sssssssslither

> Sssssss is the noise of a rotating disk.

You can read me like a book

> Disks can be read!

I'm so tiny and compact

> Compact-disk!

6 long years I took

> I don't really know this one

I can remember a lot

> You have a pretty big storage capacity

A very basic procedure

> Insert disk in the reader!

White is very important to me

> Might be virgin disks?

Beautiful for sure

> The rainbow behind CD!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this isn't the answer

Are you

> **Music**
>  Music sheets can be read, Music takes no physical space, I guess there must be a song named 6 long years or maybe some music took 6 years to write, it can definitely be tied to memories (remember a lot) or symbolically represent something. Music is actually conceptually very very very simple (basic procedure), whole notes are empty(white) in music sheets, Music is obviously beautiful, there's only the slither that doesn't fit.

Comment: Does music slither, though?

Comment: As I said, it doesn't fit. Just couldn't think of anything else... You could always go with snake charmers that play music to charm 'em though.